# Install Wordpress using composer

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am a newbie to Wordpress. I try to install Wordpress using composer.
composer.json

```
{
  "repositories": [
   {
     "type": "package",
      package": {
        "name": "wordpress",
        "type": "webroot",
         "version": "4.0",
         "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/archive/4.9.6.zip"
           },
       "require" : {
        "fancyguy/webroot-installer": "1.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "require": {
     "wordpress": "4.*",
     "fancyguy/webroot-installer": "1.0.0"
   },
  "extra": {
     "webroot-dir": "public/wp",
     "webroot-package": "wordpress"
  }
}
```

After composer install Wordpress. I change folders structure like this:

```
public
  wp
    wp-admin
    wp-includes
    ....
  wp-content
  index.php
  wp-config.php
vendor
```

Everythings works fine. When I want to create my own theme page inside public/wp-content/themes named as simple. I cannot found my theme inside the dashboard. Any suggestion please?

Comment: You should show your `wp-content` folder structure. Remember include a `style.css` file inside your theme folder to make it available from WordPress dashboard.

Comment: Is working if i download directly from http://www.wordpress.org/download. I have problem only with if I use composer to download.

Comment: you need to locate the themes directory in the config. Try bedrock by roots instead. This is a boilerplate with perfect structure for Wordpress, which give you everything what you need as developer https://roots.io/bedrock/